# Dynamic routing of a dynamics components with Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm creating an app to manage certain maintenance by the user. I've created a component that displays all the data I've entered into an array of objects. My problem is how to redirect the user to a different page for each component they click (each page must have component data). To reinderize I passed the Vue syntax $ {maintenance.id} but without getting results.

```
<card-maintenance
          v-for="manutenzione in manutenzioni"
          :key="manutenzione.id"
          :name="manutenzione.nome"
          :data="manutenzione.data"
          :durata="manutenzione.durata"
        >
        <router-link :to="`manutenzione/${manutenzione.id }`">More details</router-link>
        </card-maintenance>
```

Comment: Is your card-maintenance component needs to render anything? Why the router-link is not into your card-maintenance component?

Comment: try using @click prop in your card-maintainance component like said

Comment: ok, thanks, move the link into the components works.

Answer (score 0):

Vue is misinterpreting the javascript interpolation. Try like this:

```
<card-maintenance
          v-for="manutenzione in manutenzioni"
          :key="manutenzione.id"
          :name="manutenzione.nome"
          :data="manutenzione.data"
          :durata="manutenzione.durata"
        >
        <router-link :to="'manutenzione/' + manutenzione.id ">More details</router-link>
        </card-maintenance>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<template>
<router-link :to="`/manutenzione/${id}`"> 
  <div class="maitenanceItem">
    
    <div class="nameMaintenace">
      <p>{{ name }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="dataMaintenance">
      <p>{{ data }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="durataMaintenace">
      <p>{{ durata }}</p>
    </div>
       
  </div>
  </router-link>
</template>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).